# Portable implementation of XSLT node-set function

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am currently working on refactoring a large XSLT 1.0 Library that includes several thousand XSLT files.  The library was designed to run using MSXML and consequently has ms:node-set() calls littered throughout.  It strikes me that if we ever need to port the library to a different XSLT Engine it is going to be a mission to go through and update all the references to the node-set function.

Is it possible to implement the node-set function in a more portable fashion so there is a single point of change when it comes time to port the library?  For example, define a single custom function, say my:node-set(), that wraps/overrides the ms:node-set() function and replace all the ms:node-set() references in the library to reference my:node-set() instead.

I am not interested in solutions that involve moving to XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-specified functions are not a feature of XSLT 1.0 (though some implementations support user definition of functions as an extension). So the user-defined wrapper you have in mind will not work.  (Sigh.)  You will probably get better portability if you use the EXSLT flavor of node-set().

Comment: Good answer, extra points for having such an excellent username.